# Publishing an SQL Server CLR Assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clr

I'm developing a CLR stored procedure for my client.  There are two assemblies that are involved.  The CLR assembly that contains the "stored procedure" and an "engine" that does some work.  (I'm developing both.)  I can go into more detail on this if necessary, but I don't believe it's directly related to the problem.

When I test out my early prototype, I have Visual Studio generate the script that registers the assembly and the CLR procedure on the SQL server.  It uses the following syntax to register the assembly...

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Blah.Blah.Engine]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 0x4D5A9000030000000....

CREATE ASSEMBLY [Blah.Blah]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 0x4D5A90000300.....
```

Then it creates the procedures.  This works fine.  But, rather than send the hexadecimal bits as part of the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement, what we want to do is copy the compiled .DLL files to the disk and use the path to the assemblies to register them, like this...

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [Blah.Blah.Engine]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 'C:\MyFolder\Blah.Blah.Engine.dll'
```

However, when I do that, I get the following error:

> Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 Assembly 'Blah.Blah.Engine'
>   references assembly 'system.data.datasetextensions, version=4.0.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.', which is not
>   present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and
>   automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location
>   where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed
>   (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load
>   the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your
>   request.

Yes, my Engine is referencing system.data.datasetextensions.  But if I use the first syntax, I don't get this error.  I'd strongly prefer to not have to us the `WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` phrase and have to manually copy all the referenced assemblies into "MyFolder" on the server.  That doesn't seem like the right way to go at all.  But if sending the bits over runs correctly, why is it not working when I do it the second way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why prefer to ship a DLL instead of the hex bits? I prefer the latter myself (I'm going to need a SQL file to deploy the thing anyways so I may as well make it easier on myself and have it be the only deployment artifact).

Comment: Well, I'd prefer to have a physical .dll on disk that can be referenced or inspected.  But if this proves to be more than a simple issue to resolve, I might just end up going with the hex bits approach.  I'd prefer the physical assembly.  But not so strongly that this can be allowed to consume a significant chunk of my time.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if you have the tools to inspect DLLs on your database server and are doing so, something went sideways a couple of steps further up the chain.

Comment: Also, if you *really* need the DLL to be present, copy it to the server outside of the deployment.